# How can I copy the full clipboard in windows

Tags: python, windows

There is a feature in windows which allows you to save previously copied clipboard data and not overwrite it

[image]

How can I copy all these or modify or delete these values with python, I have tried using win32clipboard or pyperclip, but it only works with the last value

Comment: [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard).

Comment: @IInspectable can you give me a small html and js example, I am not very fluent in js, and not able to import the Windows module displayed on the webpage

Comment: Ask some Python enthusiast to generate WinRT-bindings, and take it from there. I'm not a Python enthusiast.

Comment: @IInspectable not about python, is this implementable in a webpage? with just html and js?

Comment: @IInspectable I just want a way to read and modify all the contents of this clipboard through a script, it could be js or python

Comment: `Clipboard` is a Windows Runtime type. The Windows Runtime is language agnostic. You can access it from JavaScript, C++, Rust, C#, and - in theory - Python. I can help you find the interface exposed by the OS. I cannot help you access that interface from a programming language I'm not familiar with.